# PHP sort array with czech encoding, case insensitive and without re-indexing

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm having multi-dimensional problem :) I have an array, which contains this:

```
array (33)
18 => "D3 0309/II Ševětín – Borek" (31)
19 => "D3 0311 TŘEBONÍN – KAPLICE NÁDRAŽÍ" (41)
25 => "D3 0312/I Kaplice nádraží - Nažidla" (39)
26 => "D3 0312/II - Nažidla - Dolní Dvořiště státní hranice" (59)
27 => "D3 TEST" (7)
15 => "D30310_Hodějovice-Třebonín" (29)
30 => "D4 Lety - Čimelice" (19)
29 => "D4 Milín - Lety" (16)
32 => "D4 Mirotice rozšíření" (25)
20 => "D4 křižovatka II/118 – Milín, DSP" (38)
31 => "D4 Čimelice - Mirotice" (23)
13 => "D6 Lubenec obchvat 1.etapa" (26)
23 => "D6 Nové Strašecí-Řevničov" (30)
6 => "D6 Řevničov obchvat" (21)
33 => "D8 MÚK Zdiby – rozšíření Prosecké radiály, etapa 2 – direktní větev" (80)
12 => "I/21 Trstěnice - Drmoul" (24)
2 => "I/37 Chrudim - obchvat, úsek křiž. I/17 - Slatiňany" (55)
44 => "Jirka (ostatni nesahat) - import Valbek" (39)
17 => "Klatovy" (7)
37 => "Letiste Pribram" (15)
24 => "Optimalizace traťového úseku Mstětice – Praha - Vysočany" (63)
34 => "Radost II" (9)
7 => "SOKP 512 "D1-Jesenice - Vestec" Psáry - přeložka silnice II/105" (66)
14 => "Stavba - návod" (15)
43 => "Test ě+ščřžýáíé0123465789 sss" (38)
4 => "Testovací stavba" (17)
39 => "Videnska" (8)
38 => "Vratislavice" (12)
36 => "Zvýšení kapacity trati Nymburk – Mladá Boleslav, 2.stavba" (63)
41 => "jirka test 4" (12)
22 => "test" (4)
35 => "test-D4 křižovatka II/118 – Milín" (38)
45 => "čtest" (6)
```

At first, I must keep indexes, because they are taken in select query as ID. Second, I have to sort that case-insensitive and third, I need to sort it with czech encoding. I've searched for some help, but nothing worked for me.
I will include my current code, which uses `uasort` with `strcoll` , but it sorts case-sensitive and doesn't even work for czech encoding...

```
setlocale(LC_COLLATE, 'cs_CZ.utf8');
uasort($options, 'strcoll');
```

also tried this, but with same result...

```
setlocale(LC_COLLATE, 'cs_CZ.utf8');
asort($options, SORT_LOCALE_STRING);
```

Answer (score 3):

So I finally solved it with the way I wanted to avoid.

```
$sort = function ($a, $b){
    static $czechCharsS = array('Á', 'Č', 'Ď', 'É', 'Ě' , 'Ch' , 'Í', 'Ň', 'Ó', 'Ř', 'Š', 'Ť', 'Ú', 'Ů' , 'Ý', 'Ž', 'á', 'č', 'ď', 'é', 'ě' , 'ch' , 'í', 'ň', 'ó', 'ř', 'š', 'ť', 'ú', 'ů' , 'ý', 'ž');
    static $czechCharsR = array('AZ','CZ','DZ','EZ','EZZ','HZZZ','IZ','NZ','OZ','RZ','SZ','TZ','UZ','UZZ','YZ','ZZ','az','cz','dz','ez','ezz','hzzz','iz','nz','oz','rz','sz','tz','uz','uzz','yz','zz');

    $A = str_replace($czechCharsS, $czechCharsR, $a);
    $B = str_replace($czechCharsS, $czechCharsR, $b);

    return strnatcasecmp($A, $B);
};
uasort($options, $sort);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a sort function and lower first.

```
setlocale(LC_COLLATE, 'cs_CZ.utf8');
function sortme ($a,$b){
    $a = mb_strtolower($a);
    $b = mb_strtolower($b);
    return strcoll($a,$b);
}

$options = array('Ša','šb','Šc','šd');
uasort($options, 'sortme');
print_r($options);

//result with strtolower
//Array ( [0] => Ša [1] => šb [2] => Šc [3] => šd )

//result without mb_strtolower
//Array ( [0] => Ša [2] => Šc [1] => šb [3] => šd )
```

Comment: That works as case-insensitive, but unfortunately `čtest` is still last item in array, although it should be first..

Comment: after edit: but when you add something without czech encoing, like for example `aa`, `bb`, `zz`, `yy`, items with special characters are still at last positions..

Comment: mmh, that wired. have to look more into it

Comment: solved, look at my answer, I've searched through some czech forums, and this seems to be the only solution unfortunately..